# Draw out a Battle!

Tags: mathematics, knowledge, formation-of-numbers

I'm thinking of a number. It's 5 digits long

There's a 5 between a 7 and a 2.
The second-biggest number is on the far right.
The average digit value is equal to the second-lowest digit.
The smallest digit does not divide the largest digit.
You can write it without knowing binary (tricky clue!).
No digit is neighbored by two smaller digits.
There's a 2 beside a 6.
Most of the digits are odd.

Now tell me what AWESOME job I must be thinking of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The job is

> Elite TIE Fighter Pilot in The Last Jedi (Star wars)

The number is

> 75526

And this is

> [The lego star wars code number for Elite TIE Fighter Pilot](https://www.lego.com/en-gb/starwars/products/elite-tie-fighter-pilot-75526). This also fits the title.

Explanation

> The first clue is slightly misleading, as the 5 isn't directly in the middle of the 7 and 2. However as we know a 6 is next to a 2, then 7+5+2+6 = 20. The only number which can be added to this to give a whole number average, and have the second smallest digit as the average is 5. 6 must therefore be last , so the only two options are
>
> 1. 75526
> 2. 57526
>
> No digit is neighboured by two smaller digits, so this rules out 2 because 7 is neighboured by two 5s. This leaves 1. and that gave the answer...

There's a 5 between a 7 and a 2.

> Theres actually 2

The second-biggest number is on the far right.

> The 6 which is second largest

The average digit value is equal to the second-lowest digit.

> 7+5+5+2+6 = 25. 25/5 = 5, the second smallest digit

The smallest digit does not divide the largest digit.

> 2 does not divide 7

You can write it without knowing binary (tricky clue!).

> No 0s or 1s

No digit is neighbored by two smaller digits.

> No two neighbours are smaller than the one in the middle.

There's a 2 beside a 6.

> At the end

Most of the digits are odd.

> 3/5 are odd

Comment: Close, but not quite. There was a tricky clue in there that I didn't label as tricky. Math grammar. Once you have the right number, it won't take long to find the job!

Comment: @KevinCuredMeat hmmmm... unless I have misunderstood a clue I'm pretty sure this is the only possible answer... (Is 0 allowed?)

Comment: i believe there is 5 between 7 and 2 could mean 7xx52 or 7x5x2 or ...

Comment: @Oray aaah thats the clue I misunderstood... of course...

Comment: @KevinCuredMeat Think I have it now

Comment: That's it! I wasn't sure if "top result on Google" merited the "knowledge" tag, but I put it on there to be safe. Nice, fast work!

Comment: @KevinCuredMeat yeah I think the tag is appropriate. One thing though, I have found two valid answers (see update), but I haven't solved the binary clue. Does the solution to that rule out 57526?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil The clue was meant to state that there were no zeroes or ones. And you're right, there are two valid answers, but I figured the requirement that it lead to a meaningful job would compensate for that. I guess I could add in another restriction to remove the other soltuion, but since it's been solved that doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: @KevinCuredMeat I think you should add in another rule, a logical deduction puzzle should have a unique answer. The binary clue seems obvious now :)